# Unity Extension method with coroutine

Tags: c#, unity

Is it possible to have extension methods that starts coroutines? Id like to have an extension method for the GameObject that checks if itself has a renderer and a material and then lerps the color to a target color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do it. Since extensions are static and they cannot inherit the `MonoBehaviour` that contains the `StartCoroutine` methods.

Comment: Ok, then i know its a dead end. Very useful information. :)